# How exactly do you extract the "bio" and "rules" texts from a Twitch stream webpage?

Tags: php, dom, chromium, headless-browser, twitch

I've tried:

1. cURL. The HTML returned does not include any mention of this data.
2. Their API. I've combed through the entire documentation and specifically asked them about it, and their API simply doesn't have this feature.
3. 72 different versions and variations of Chromium and Chrome, tested on multiple OSes over months, but they never "dump the DOM" when asked to headlessly fetch a URL and output the post-JavaScript DOM as text.
4. Firefox doesn't even theoretically support "dumping the DOM". Its "guides" talk about installing a bunch of Node.js and Selenium stuff, which I don't want on my machine.
5. Phantom.js and many other "headless browser" projects are long since dead/abandoned.
6. Selenium has no official PHP library/code examples, forcing one to rely on scary, unreliable, prone-to-disappear-overnight third-party libraries. I've also spent weeks trying to understand how to use Selenium without success.

It appears as if the data in question is fetched as JSON blobs with JavaScript after the page has been loaded in a full-fledged browser, encrypted, and then somehow decrypted and displayed on the webpage.

I hate modern websites...

Comment: It's not protected/encrypted but is somewhat tricky to scrape if you dont know the channel id, but not impossible, if you know the channel id it's easy you just need to query /gql endpoint with a ChannelPanels operationName, and it returns an array of the panels (the sections your after), then just loop over them and look for the title to match against Chat Rules or Description, or whatever the title of the panel the owner has set.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Doesn't work. The most "promising" output from that is: "{"errors":[{"message":"no operations in query document"}],"extensions":{"durationMilliseconds":1,"operationName":"ChannelPanels"}}"

URL: https://gql.twitch.tv/gql
Type: POST
JSON POST data: [ 'operationName' => 'ChannelPanels' ]
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [ 'Client-Id: blablabla' ]

Replace "blablabla" with the "Client-id" I found in the network tab and which I only use for testing, but don't know how I'd grab for the actual mechanism...